# Only getting the index for the current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a pretty basic app. I've managed to install devise. The idea is to have users who have created challenges (1 to many relationship).
I want the logged in user to be able to see all the challenges they have created.

I order to do this am I correct in thinking that I can pass the current user id as a parameter to just get the challenges of the current user as follows (assuming the view is set up correctly)

```
      <%= link_to challenges_path(user_id: current_user.id), class: 'expandable' %>
```

challenges controller

```
def index
    @challenges = Challenge.all
    render :layout => false
  end
```

Comment: No. You're not telling Rails what to do with this `user_id`. Could you show your routes as well ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the default behaviour you want for the index of the `challenges`, then you can simply change your controller action directly, and no need to modify your `link_to` to add `user_id`

challenges controller

```
def index
    @challenges = Challenge.where(user: current_user)
end
```

Now if you want to change the behavior only if the `user_id` GET param is set, you can keep your `link_to` like this and modify your controller this way

```
def index
    @challenges = params[:user_id] ? Challenge.where(user: current_user) : Challenge.all
end
```